# SFTP directory has too many files

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I am using Python and paramiko to get files via SFTP. Recently file number has grown up to the ~56k and now I get "OverflowError Python int too large to convert to C long" <s>when I try to listdir()</s> when I try to connect. Here is my code:

```
transport = paramiko.Transport(host)
transport.connect(username=username, password=password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)  # fails here
all_xmls = sftp.listdir(path=path_to_xml)
sftp.close()
transport.close()
```

I am interested in:

- is it possible to get particular files when their name format is
  already known?
- is there a way to iterate through files without listdir()?
- another way to solve my problem. How can I get these files? Is there
  a better tool for my case?

**UPDATE 1**:
paramiko's log output:

```
DEB [20150819-12:18:26.055] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Switch to new keys ...
DEB [20150819-12:18:26.056] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Attempting password auth...
DEB [20150819-12:18:26.223] thr=1   paramiko.transport: userauth is OK
INF [20150819-12:18:26.285] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Authentication (password) successful!
DEB [20150819-12:18:26.288] thr=2   paramiko.transport: [chan 1] Max packet in: 34816 bytes
ERR [20150819-12:18:26.348] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Unknown exception: Python int too large to convert to C long
ERR [20150819-12:18:26.351] thr=1   paramiko.transport: Traceback (most recent call last):
ERR [20150819-12:18:26.351] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1442, in run
ERR [20150819-12:18:26.351] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     self._handler_table[ptype](self, m)
ERR [20150819-12:18:26.351] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1848, in _parse_channel_open_success
ERR [20150819-12:18:26.351] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     server_window_size = m.get_int()
ERR [20150819-12:18:26.351] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\message.py", line 140, in get_int
ERR [20150819-12:18:26.351] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     return util.inflate_long(self.get_binary())
ERR [20150819-12:18:26.351] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\message.py", line 198, in get_binary
ERR [20150819-12:18:26.351] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     return self.get_bytes(self.get_size())
ERR [20150819-12:18:26.351] thr=1   paramiko.transport:   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\message.py", line 108, in get_bytes
ERR [20150819-12:18:26.351] thr=1   paramiko.transport:     b = self.packet.read(n)
ERR [20150819-12:18:26.351] thr=1   paramiko.transport: OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
ERR [20150819-12:18:26.351] thr=1   paramiko.transport:
```

**UPDATE 2**:
I've found that exceeding packet. This is the number of bytes - 4294967040 (added simple print to the paramiko code)

**UPDATE 3**:
I've found [big tread at the github](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/353) of the paramiko about that problem (it was first result with the right search query, shame on me). They say paramiko/message.py needs to be fixed. [Commit #482](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/pull/482/files) is all about it.
I will spectate how it works and then post an answer.

Comment: ~56k is many orders of magnitudes smaller than long. Is there a file bigger than 2GB or 4GB in the folder? The amount of files should be no trouble.

Comment: @Kay, no, there are not such big files. The total size of all files is under 800 MB. Added log output if it could help

Comment: Are you sure you identified the correct line of code? The Paramiko log looks like it's failing while opening the sftp channel. I wonder if you're having [this problem](http://www.openssh.com/faq.html#2.9)? It apparently  manifests as an error about a packet that's too large.

Comment: @Kenster, you are right about the line of code. Failure happens earlier when connecting (fixed question). I've tried your link. I'm using Windows now and in Git bash this "ssh myhost /usr/bin/true" gives me "ssh: connect to host pstw15249 port 22: Bad file number". I guess this doesn't make much sense. Though using WinSCP I still can work with files manually.

Comment: thanks for warning @Kenster i will deleted my answer. But my idea you worked with stream, not output(about of packet size error).